# Как сохранить место прокрутки страницы после перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5, scss

Я пользуюсь VS Code и там же запускаю localhost для авто перезагрузки страницы (после сохранения файла). Но проблема в том, что после этой перезагрузки прокрутка страницы возвращается наверх. Происходит это только при сохранении файла стилей (scss и css). 
Пробовал делать с localStorage, но все равно не хочет работать.
Подскажите как сохранить прокрутку, ибо скролить каждый раз до нужного места, не самый лучший вариант. Вот код для localStarage:

```
window.onload = function () {
   window.scrollTo(0, +localStorage.getItem('page_scroll'));
   document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      localStorage.setItem('page_scroll', window.pageYOffset);
   });
}
```

Comment: "Пробовал делать с localStorage, но все равно не хочет работать" — подозреваю, потому что localStorage хранит только строки, а вам нужно число, чтобы прокрутить. Пробуйте `....scrollTop = +localStorage.getItem('...')` — плюсик перед строкой превращает её в число. А есть еще `parseFloat()`

Comment: сделал как вы сказали, работает только в открытом файле html в браузере. а с localhost все так само, скролится на верх ((

Comment: в куку сохранять надо. кука лучше

Comment: Вы забыли код показать.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, браузер сам сохраняет прокрутку в нужном месте.

Если она слетает, значит в какой-то момент контента на странице становится меньше, чем положение прокрутки. Если проблема возникает только в dev-режиме, то не стоит забивать код костылями, которые там не нужны. Можно попробовать расширение, позволяющее добавлять скрипты к страницам и в нём сохранять в `sessionStorage` положение проктуртrи из `unload`, а в по таймауту после загрузки восстанавливать его.